# Is it possible to prevent automatic moving to completed chunk in RStudio using RMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

Suppose I have 2 chunks, one 10 lines long followed by one 1000 lines long. I start running the first chunk then scroll to the bottom of the page before it finishes. When it finishes, the view in the file editor moves up to the first chunk. Is it possible to prevent this behavior?